# Как дешифровать введённую последовательность байтов?

Tags: python-3.x, строки, utf-8, шифрование, byte

Предположим, что у нас есть строка, представляющая из себя последовательность байтов: **'\xc7\xb4\xc7\xae\xc8\x96'**. Ее вводят с помощью обычного input()-а. Как дешифровать эти строчные байты?

Я понимаю, что если использовать `b'\xc7\xb4\xc7\xae\xc8\x96'.decode('utf-8')` то проблема решается очень просто, но что делать со строкой, а не с готовыми байтами?

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> import ast
>>> a = input()
b'\xc7\xb4\xc7\xae\xc8\x96'
>>> a
"b'\\xc7\\xb4\\xc7\\xae\\xc8\\x96'"
>>> b = ast.literal_eval(a)
>>> b
b'\xc7\xb4\xc7\xae\xc8\x96'
>>> b.decode('utf-8')
'ǴǮȖ'
```

Answer (score 1):

Сконвертируйте в `bytes`, убрав `\x`:

```
>>> bytes.fromhex(a.replace('\\x', '')).decode('utf-8')
ǴǮȖ
```